# Are there other ways of styling HTML content to uppercase other than CSS text-transform and JS .toUpperCase?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, text-styling

I have a WP site with "baskerville2" theme and am trying to remove uppercase styling to some menu items.

I found some 'text-transform: uppercase' rules in the stylesheet and have removed these  - as well as adding 'html {text-transform: none !important;}' for good measure.

Have also searched JS assets for any instance of toUpperCase, and there are none.

Still the menu items are uppercase, so I'm wondering if they could be styled some other way?

This really has me stumped since, the theme creator himself recommends 'text-transform: normal;' as per this page: https://allaboutbasic.com/2017/03/21/baskerville-2-by-anders-noren-modifications-of-header-footer-sidebar-contents-customization-and-documentations/

- but even the code given there doesn't work.

Comment: How about JavaScript as in el.style.textTransform? And what do you see as the CSS when you inspect some element that has still got uppercase?

Comment: It's hard to tell without inspecting the actual page. From your example, it's `text-transform: uppercase` removed from two classes and the whole navigation is without uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

Panic over... It seems I had a browser window still open with an unsaved edit on the site custom css. Somehow, this caused my css changes made on another bowser window not to update.

So the text-transform change does work after all - no mystery!

Answer (score -1):

in your website text-decoration is uppercase yet

[image]

Comment: No luck with that I'm afraid, again, tried 'html { text-transform: none; text-decoration: none; }' i it clearly works on the main content - It's in the header and footer that nothing changes.

Comment: try with Inspect element to find where is the problem;